# Maven Dependencies Not Resolving in IntelliJ IDEA - "Broken Classes Paths" Errors

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I'm working on a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA, and I've run into a persistent issue where several dependencies are reported as having "broken classes paths" in the Project Structure dialog. I've tried a variety of common fixes without success, including:

- Re-importing the Maven project
- Invalidating the IntelliJ cache and restarting
- Deleting the problematic directories in `.m2/repository` and re-downloading dependencies
- Ensuring that the Maven Central Repository is accessible and that all plugin and dependency versions are correct
- Running `mvn clean install -U` from the command line to force updates

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. The `pom.xml` appears to be correctly structured, and the artifacts exist in the Maven Central Repository. Here is a snippet of my `pom.xml`:

[Pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cCAq.png)

[log errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ofl7.png)

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or could provide insight into what might be causing this and how to resolve it? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit : I use IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition) , JDK 1.8, maven 3.8.1

Comment: Which version of IDEA Intellij do you use?.. which JDK, Maven version etc. do you use?

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition) , JDK 1.8, maven 3.8.1

Comment: Please upgrade IntelliJ version... we have 2024 in the meantime... also Maven itself (Maven 3.9.6 https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and maybe you should think about upgrading to newer JDK version

Comment: As the error message states, something has prevented Maven from downloading the Artifact from Maven Central. There might be a number of reasons for that. Could you please share the full error message?